# Scikit image otsu thresholding producing zero threshold

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, image-thresholding

I am doing some preprocessing on an image, After applying [Otsu thresholding](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.threshold_otsu) on the image I am getting zero threshold while on another image it’s working fine

```
from skimage import filters
from skimage.io import imread

img = imread(img_path, as_gray=True)

threshold = filters.threshold_otsu(img)
print(threshold)
```

[H-S-1-G-01.tif](https://gofile.io/?c=20PL9f)
[image]

**Threshold** : 0

[original_1_1.png](https://gofile.io/?c=EKJVwe)
[image]

**Threshold** : 204

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BogdanDoicin Why threshold is zero for 1st image and not for 2nd image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct result. Your image is bi-level, it only has values of 0 and 255, so 0 is a threshold that will split the image into two values correctly when you do the next step:

```
threshold = filters.threshold_otsu(img)
binary = im > threshold
```

Try it for yourself with some dummy *"images"*:

```
filters.threshold_otsu(np.array([0,255],dtype=np.uint8))
0

filters.threshold_otsu(np.array([7,12],dtype=np.uint8)) 
7

filters.threshold_otsu(np.array([7,8,11,12],dtype=np.uint8))
8
```